# How do I align the text and the image to create something that is similar to this image

Tags: html, css

This is the image I have recreate 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO6kI.jpg

This is what I have
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3btuB.jpg

How do I push the text above. I tried margin/padding-bottom and it doesn't work

```css
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 900px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#header{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

#header img{
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#header h1{
  margin-left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x75">
    <h1>The Power To Serve</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `position` of your `#header h1` to `relative`, and add `bottom: 20px` (You can change it to whatever you want)

*CSS*:

```
#header img{
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#header h1{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;    
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/kqu7sken/5/

Answer (score 1):

putting `h1` in a div i think can help you.

```
 <div id="header">
     <div class="logo">       
          <img src="logo2.png" alt="Logo">
     </div>
     <div class="mytitle">
        <h1>The Power To Serve</h1>
     </div>
</div>
```

and try to fix size of it

```
#header{height: 100px; width: 100%; }
.logo{width: 100px; margin-left: 200px; float:left;}
.mytitle{margin-left: 350px; width:300px;} /*margin-left should be more than the 
image width + image margin-left at least*/
```

You can try to correct this code (size width and margin) to get really what you need !!!